# Given two datetime objects, find the months/days in between?

Tags: python-3.x

In python, what I need is, given two dates;

i.e

```
date1 = '2021-11-03'
date2 = '2022-01-02'
```

I want to product a list of each day in between as a datetime object, so a list of

```
days_between = ['2022-01-01', '2021-12-31', '2021-12-30', etc, etc]
```

I also need to find the months between both, so in this case, I would want a list with say..

```
months_between = ['2022-01-01', '2021-11-01', '2021-12-01']
```

right now, i've been using something like this to accomplish this;

```
# Get all lessons
lessons = get_lessons_between(start=start, end=end, obj=True)

# Store the dates
dates = []
for lesson in lessons:
    date = convert_to_dt_obj(lesson.date)

    if date not in dates:
        dates.append(date)

series = {}

for date in dates:
    for lesson in lessons:
        if convert_to_dt_obj(lesson.date) == date:
            if lesson.date not in series.keys():
                series[lesson.date] = lesson.value
            else:
                series[lesson.date] += lesson.value

tmp_lst = []
for k, v in series.items():
    tmp_lst.append([k, v])
```

What i'm working is dates inside a database that are in string format 'YYYY-MM-DD'. I'm trying to normalize the data for some charting using APEX charts/vue on my frontend.

What I would prefer is to have the dates as a list between any two dates and just lookup in the database based on each one in the list so I could say..

```
for day in days_between:
    .. do some database queries
```

any thoughts or help is appreicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial answer (days only):

```
python3.9
Python 3.9.5 (default, Nov 23 2021, 15:27:38) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from datetimerange import DateTimeRange
>>> date1 = '2021-11-03'
>>> date2 = '2022-01-02'
>>> DateTimeRange(date1,date2).get_timedelta_second()/(3600*24)
60.0
```

Comment: accepted as answer, because the module you pointed out gives me what I need.. for anyone else looking for the answer, here you do;

          # for months
          for t in time_range.range(relativedelta(months=+1)): # use days=1 for days
              print(t)